# Why number of sub-directories inside a folder in amazon EC2 is different with Ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I copy a large folder from ubuntu (12.04) to amazon S3

```
aws s3 sync UBUNTU_DIR s3://BUCKET/
```

and then from S3 to an EC2 of an Elastic Beanstalk application.

```
aws s3 sync s3://BUCKET/ EC2_DIR
```

Everything transferred correctly with no errors.

When I get the number of Objects in my amazon S3 bucket using amazon console, it doesn't consider the subfolders inside the folder. It means that the number of objects in S3 equals to number of files inside the ubuntu directory `find UBUNTU_DIR/ -type f | wc -l` which is fine.

Now my question is, when I copy the files from S3 to EC2 with no error, again number of files inside the copied folder is same with the ubuntu source, but why the number of sub-folders inside the copied folder in EC2 is about 2000 less than the ubuntu source folder?

`find EC2_DIR/ -type d | wc -l` : shows 20172

`find UBUNTU_DIR/ -type d | wc -l` : shows 22231

I searched a lot, but didn't find any reason for such difference. Thank you  for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have empty sub directories in `UBUNTU_DIR`. `aws s3 sync` does not create empty folders.

See: [aws s3 sync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)

> Syncs directories and S3 prefixes. Recursively copies new and updated
>   files from the source directory to the destination. **Only creates
>   folders in the destination if they contain one or more files**.

```
find UBUNTU_DIR -type d -empty | wc -l
```

will return the number of empty directories and it should be ~2000

Comment: Thant's right, I didn't expect that, but it seems I have many empty directories under the ubuntu directory. Thanks for your help. :)